# Is it possible for my firefox browser and my chrome browser to sync their visited url list

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, history

so that :visited on one css gives the same answer as on the other? and links that turn color on one browser also (sooner or later) turn color on the other browser (maybe after a page reload).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly a lot of options available if you just wanted *bookmark* syncing. Tools like [Eversync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fvd-synchronizer/) etc. can do this.

Syncing *history* too doesn't seem to be as common. In my searches, I found a desktop tool called [RecentX](https://www.conceptworld.com/RecentX/Access-Internet-History-From-All-Browsers) which claims to collect history and bookmarks from Chrome, Firefox and IE into a central database of sorts. Whether it syncs them *back* to each of the browsers, though, I'm not certain. You could give it a try or ask their customer support.

Comment: thanks for the recentx link, I would just like the browser to change the color on my links because they have been visited on another browser